# How to create Angular2 Modal Component WITHOUT Bootstrap and WITHOUT jQuery?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

All searches on this topic lead to importing existing components that depend on Bootstrap.

I don't want to use Bootstrap. I want my own simpler HTML markup and way less class names to remember and crowd an already-complicated markup.

I'm fairly comfortable with components, component lifecycle, services, templates, events, observables, and other Angular2 concepts, but I am only able to build an application with nested components whose "parent page" end up in <router-outlet>.

I feel that there may be some lesser-known concepts of Angular2 that most tutorials and even video courses don't address, that would allow me to achieve modal popups. I think I will have to somehow "hack" the DOM to insert some html at the root of the entire webpage so that I can absolutely position the modal. I don't want to use jQuery because it might violate Angular2's inner workings and principles. If possible, I want to know an Angular2-safe way to manipulate the DOM if I have to - I prefer not to chase DOM elements from component code.

I do not only want alert confirmations and prompts. I want to be able to put a form-component on the modal window that would allow the user to save something to the database or choose an item from a list.

I know I'm asking for a lot, but specifically:

1. What html markup and CSS should my popup component have at a minimum? Ideally, I want to put a translucent cover over the entire page, and the actual modal on top of it. to ensure that users can't click outside that modal window.
2. How, if absolutely required, would services and observables be used to pull this?
3. Can I just include this modal component's markup (as defined in its @Component({}) decorator) on a host/parent component and open it?
4. Ideally, on the host component's code, I want to be able to call something like `selectRecordModal.onSelected(selectedItem => { .... }).onCancelled( () => { ... });`

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/  Visit this link ,its not using jquery as for as i know.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/ngx-bootstrap look at the dependency Its not using jquery,they only use bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using material design? If so they call their 'modals' just overlays as a more generic feature as they can be used for everything from menus to alerts.

Otherwise, you can easily do modals with mostly css and a simple onclick event for loading/closing. Infact you can do it with just css but with limited browser support.

Something like this:
http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/#!
Which even supports  ie8 (kind of)

Comment: In general, I have not considered this. I will look into it, though, for personal use. My supervisor is adamantly against modern looks, which is part of the reason why I'm staying away from modern UI frameworks.

Comment: Ouch that's painful. I've added an external link for a ready made pure css modal.